# Hardware square root gcc

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I'm trying to use the hardware instructions to compute some mathematical functions. For example the square root (sqrtpd instruction). I'm compiling my C code with GCC.

Does Anybody know what are the gcc options to force to compile with the hardware instructions and not to use the libc? Or if I need to do something special on my source code? (Without writing asm code).

Comment: -ffast-math, -march...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On gcc you should use `__builtin_ia32_sqrtpd`.

Comment: This is what I need. But now I have another question, you know if the same exists for sine and cosine? I din't found anything on the gcc documentation.

Comment: gcc has sin/cos builtin [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html). But if you're looking for performance you should use another SSE2/3/4 optimized library such as [this](http://gruntthepeon.free.fr/ssemath/)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use optimization flags. -O1 generates

`sqrtsd %xmm1, %xmm0`

in assembly code. Try using -S flag with gcc to generate assembly and look how optimization flags works.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you just write the desired hardware instruction in assembly code directly.

As far as I know, writing assembly code directly in c code is possible. It is called Inline Assembly. [ See here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html ]

Comment: I know how to write assembly on C code. I'm just working on a project that can help us a lot if GCC can translate into hardware instructions.